# Replace negative values in UNIX

Tags: unix

Team,

I have pipeline delimited file like below,

```
100|0.0|yyy|zzz
200|3.5|www|ttt
300|-5.134|uuu|kkk
400|-9.823798|ooo|ppp
```

I need to replace the zero and negative values with "NA".

Expected Output:

```
100|NA|yyy|zzz
200|3.5|www|ttt
300|NA|uuu|kkk
400|NA|ooo|ppp
```

Please help on this.

Comment: pluse uno for sample input and expected input, but minus uno because of no attempt to solve your problem. Edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem and we can help you understand where you where in error. Good luck.

Comment: Do you only want to replace them in the second field? Are all fields with an `.`, do they can be matched with `[-]{0,1}[0-9]+[.][0-9]+`, something like `...| grep -Eo "[-]{0,1}[0-9]+[.][0-9]+"`. Maybe try `sed` when `awk` is not your cup of tea. And show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

AWK would be a good tool for this.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} 
{for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) {if($i > 0){out=out"|"$i}else{out=out"|NA"}}; 
print substr(out,2)}'
```

We set the field separator (FS) to "|"
Loop over all field numbers (1 through NF).
If larger than 0, append |$i, pipe plus field value.
If not we append |NA.
After the loop is done, we print except the first character which is still a pipe.

Note that now ascii comparison is done.

Comment: I tried the above code snippet, but getting different result, 100|0.0|yyy|zzz
100|0.0|yyy|zzz|200|3.5|www|ttt
100|0.0|yyy|zzz|200|3.5|www|ttt|300|NA|uuu|kkk
100|0.0|yyy|zzz|200|3.5|www|ttt|300|NA|uuu|kkk|400|NA|ooo|ppp

Comment: My bad, missed that you also want 0 to be interpreted as NA. In that case I will edit the answer.

Comment: That would be of great help!

Comment: @Rajesh You should understand the `awk` command before you use it. When you do understand, any idea where to add an `=` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\| '{sub(/^-.*|^0.*/,"NA",$2)}1' OFS=\| file

100|NA|yyy|zzz
200|3.5|www|ttt
300|NA|uuu|kkk
400|NA|ooo|ppp
```